# ¿Qué significa "díeste"?

Tags: significado, palabras-raras

Hojeando mi ejemplar de "El hobbit" encuentro el siguiente texto en el preámbulo:

> Las runas eran letras que en un principio se escribían mediante cortes o incisiones en madera, piedra o metal. En los **díeste** relato los Enanos las utilizaban con regularidad, especialmente en registros privados o secretos.

No encuentro la palabra "díeste" ni en el DLE ni en el CORDE. ¿Qué quiso decir pues el traductor con esta palabra?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Podría ser una errata, pequeño hobbit. En otras versiones dice:

> Las runas eran letras que en un principio se escribían mediante cortes o incisiones en madera, piedra, o metal. En los **días** de este relato los Enanos las utilizaban con regularidad,
>
> Fuente: [quieroleer](http://www.quieroleer.com.ar/libros/el-hobbit/1.html)

Idem para otras fuentes/versiones como [wattpad](https://www.wattpad.com/596795121-el-hobbit-%0D-j-r-r-tolkien), [Coursehero](https://www.coursehero.com/file/14248364/JRR-Tolkien-El-Hobbit/), etc.

Busca parte del texto por Internet sin incluir "díeste".

Comment: Sí, en un principio pensé que podría ser una errata, pero me extrañó que estuviera en un sitio tan prominente y tan pronto en el texto, así que pregunté por si acaso...

Comment: No sé hasta dónde es fácil comprobar los de la errata (siguientes ediciones que no contengan "díeste"?). Lo mismo alguien nos sorprende con alguna otra respuesta en la que explica que es un arcaísmo de algún tipo. Veremos.

Answer (score 3):

Parece una errata clara e incluso una traducción poco ajustada si la comparamos con el original en inglés [consultado a través de Google Books]

> Runes were old letters originally used for cutting or scratching on
>   wood, stone, or metal, and so were thin and angular. At the time of
>   this tale only the Dwarves made use of them, especially for private or
>   secret records.

Nótese que no aparece específicamente la palabra **días** - que me parece correcta emplear en este caso, ya que queda mejor que *tiempo* o *momento*, literariamente hablando - , pero tampoco ocupa su lugar arcaísmo alguno. Destacar que el traductor omite que **solo** los enanos las usaban y añade de su cosecha un **regularidad** que no aparece en el original.